# ORA Invalid Number

Tags: sql, oracle

```
UPDATE DB
SET ID = 400
WHERE 'ID2' = 400;
```

I have two questions:
First: I don't really understand why number needs '' and ID not.
(I get errors if number doesn't have them).
Second: Why do I get the "invalid number" error message?

I could put 400 in '', but that results in zero results.

The ID attribute is number(3,0) and the ID2 attribute is varchar(3BYTE).

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'ID2'` is not the name of a column, it is a string literal. Single quotes are used in SQL to enclose strings.  Since you are comparing a string literal to a numeric literal, the server is trying to convert the string to a number, causing the invalid number error.

(You can enclose column names in double-quotes if you want them to be interpreted exactly.  This is generally used if someone has created columns with mixed case or reserved characters in the names.  Probably not the case here.)

If the `ID2` column is VARCHAR, and you want to find rows where its values equals the string '400', then I think your predicate should be `WHERE ID2 = '400'`.  If that gives you an error, what is it?

Comment: Thanks! But it doesn't work either. I still get an ORA-00904 this way.

Comment: Resolved the issue. My search skills failed me yesterday. The problem was because of " in the DDL.